# Grails - How to disable db connection for script running

Tags: grails

I have a grails app that has some run-scripts that I want to run in my build process.  I'm using a build process with ant that does a bunch of things before it creates a war file.

However, the running of the script wants to connect to the database in the datasource file.  So that fails.  I want to be able to configure the datasource file so that it has a connection during the running of the app on dev, qa, staging and production servers.  But I want it to ignore the connection definitions during running of special scripts on my build server.

What is the proper way to do this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing to do would be to create a new environment that uses an in-memory database, e.g.

```
environments {
   nodb {
      dataSource {
         url = "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:nodb"
         driverClassName = "org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"
         username = "sa"
         password = ""
      }
   }
   development {
   ...
}
```

and then specify it when running the script:

```
grails -Dgrails.env=nodb <scriptname> <args>
```

Comment: It worked.  However, I did end up changing the driver to driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver".
As always, Thanks Burt!